# Is there any way to support RSA using the crypto-js library?

Tags: encryption, cryptojs

I am using `AES-GCM` from `crypto-js` presently. The intent would be to change to `RSA` for the asymmetric cryptography.  Is the following statement correct https://community.postman.com/t/http-message-signing-using-rsa-sha256/1791
?

> However, CryptoJS doesn’t support RSA, and it’s the only crypto
> library available in the Postman Sandbox. So I’m sort of stuck, unless
> I implement a RSA-SHA256 signing algorithm myself.
>
> Now, I’ve noticed that crypto-js hasn’t had a single commit for a year
> on GitHub,

I would really prefer to stick with the `crypto-js` library since it was difficult to use the built-in `SubtleCrypto` and now we have a framework built around the `crypto-js` libraries. That would basically have to be scrapped to go to `SubtleCrypto`.   Pointers appreciated.

Comment: No. CryptoJS is a JavaScript library for symmetric, but not asymmetric encryption, i.e. it does _not_ support RSA.

Comment: @Topaco Thx for the confirmation - I did pivot to `Tweet-nacl` after posting this. Feel free to post an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Topaco mentions the `crypto-js` is a *symmetric* encryption library only. I did pivot to `tweet-nacl` and it is working well.